# Checking if a word does not exist in a string Python

Tags: python, list, if-statement

So I want to check if a word from my list exists in the message so, I did this:

```
if any([x in message.content for x in List]):
```

But now I want also check if a word from my list doesn't exist but, if I do, that it won't work. It just ignores the blacklist

```
if any([x in message.content for x in List]) and not any([x in message.content for x in Blacklist]):
```

Why is it like that?

Comment: What do you mean by "it just ignores the blacklist"? The `if` statement evaluates to `True` if `message.content` contains an item in `List`, but not an item in `Blacklist`, as expected. If there's a word from `Blacklist`, the statement evaluates to `False`, again as expected. I don't see any issues with the code, it seems to be working as intended, so you really should give an example as to what you consider problematic.

Comment: This isn't hard to figure out if you try to debug it... One note, `and all(x not in ...)` is probably faster than `not any(x in ...)`.

Comment: @thebjorn `all()` is slower because it must check every item, but `any()` stops checking as soon as it finds one match.

Comment: @JohnGordon but here you're doing negative matches, and all will stop immediately when it doesn't match.

Comment: @thebjorn Yeah, you're right, dunno what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking if any element is not in message.
You could try this.

```
x = ['hello','there']
msg = 'hello sir'
wordsNotExistant = [words for words in msg.split(' ') if words not in x]
```

Output

```
['sir']
```

All the words in the given message that cannot be found in `x` will be appended to `wordNotExistant`